# How to use printer Toshiba e-studio 163 when there is no drivers for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, printer, print-drivers

I have good printer : Toshiba e-studio163 and computer with Windows 10. There is no drivers for Windows 10, even from Toshiba page.
I have googled with no results.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: what you tried forcing the windows 7 or 8.1 drivers?

Comment: yes - bad windows version.

Comment: does it just blue screen?

Comment: No, only message from program http://www.driverscape.com/download/toshiba-e-studio163.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing manually.

Steps:

1. Try downloading this https://www.driverscape.com/files/allinone/TOSHIBA_100407_TOSHIBAVIEWERV2_v104.zip and then unzip it.
2. Go to the Device Manager (type `device manager` in Cortana or the Start Menu).
3. Plugin in your device and locate it in the device manager.
4. Right click on the device and click `Update driver`.
5. Select `browse my computer for drivers`.
6. Locate the unzipped directory.
7. Continue....